Infinite Loop in React errorElement
I have a problem with an infinite loop/memory leak in react. The global error handler is initiated like this:
export const routesConfig: RouteObject[] = [
{
    path: '/',
    element: <App />,
    errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
    children: [
        (all the routes)
    ],
},

];
The user session will timeout after some time or if the user logs out manually. If there is another tab open or the user comes back, the server will return 401. So the first thing I check in the errorPage is this
if (err.statusCode === 401) {
    window.location.href = '/?nocache=' + Date.now();
}

But this leads to an infinite loop and the browser crashes. The browser has hundreds of calls to the startpage with nocache but they all get cancelled. It seems like this window.location.href is not executed completely. If I do it manually, it works.
I have a simple, working solution:
let reloadTriggered = false;
if (err.statusCode === 401) {
    if (!reloadTriggered) {
        reloadTriggered = true;
        window.location.href = '/?nocache=' + Date.now();
    }
    return;
}

But what I am doing here does not seem like best practices in react. Any advice here?

Instead of using window.location.href, use useNavigate from react-router.
const navigate = useNavigate();

if (err.statusCode === 401) {
    navigate('/?nocache=' + Date.now())
}

